# How do I change the from address (noreply@localhost) in Moodle's messaging?

Tags: php, moodle

I'm working on my first Moodle system and have got most things working the way I want but I'm stuck on one thing for which I can't seem to find the answer by googling around.

When I send out a message to participants on a course, the from address of the email is noreply@localhost. I want to change this address to something else but can't figure out where I need to do this. Does anyone know how I can change this?

Thanks in advance
Ziad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log in as a system administrator and go to [your moodle root]/admin/settings.php?section=mail and then update the "No reply address" - I think that's all you need!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried your suggestion but I get a section error. I don't seem to have the mail section open to me. I am logged in as the main admin. Does the mail section need to be enabled separately somehow before you can access it?

Comment: No, That shouldn't be necessary. There may be other settings that control whether e-mails are globally enabled, but those wouldn't stop you seeing the mail settings. Can you check that you are logged in as a root administrator rather than one of the Moodle Management roles? Make sure that you can see 'Site administration' and go to Users/Permissions/Site Administrators to check that you are on the list.

Comment: Ah I found it, the section is 'messagesettingemail', not 'mail'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to make it clear, the URL for email settings is:

[your moodle root]/admin/settings.php?section=messagesettingemail

Answer (score 0):

In case the `from` or the `noreplyaddress` has to be changed **on the fly** (while still leaving the default settings in tact), the following can be done:

1) in the `$from` (which happens to be an `stdClass()` object), the value of `$from->maildisplay` can be set to the desired address
2) while calling the `email_to_user()`, the 8th parameter should be set to `true`.

As a result, the `email_to_user()` will take care to display the value set in step 1 above in the sent mail.

**FYI -** The `email_to_user()` function is available at *[your-moodle-root]/lib/moodlelib.php*